# Unable to connect Google Compute Engine instance via SSH in browser

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

i am new to google cloud,i just deployed my first instance it was working fine till yesterday, i used last time to set email server using this tutorial [email server](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-2-arming-your-server-with-postfix-dovecot/4/), but now i am unable to connect ssh in browser and also with google cloud sdk in terminal.

Website is running fine,I don't know what happened Please help

the error message in browser

```
Connection Failed, and we are unable to connect VM on port 22.
```

the error message in terminal

```
Warning: Permanently added 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

And serial console output its shows

```
Jul 8 10:09:26 Instance sshd[10103]: error: Could not load host key:/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

Jul 8 10:09:27 Instance sshd[10103]: User username from 0.0.0.0 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers

Jul 8 10:09:27 Instance sshd[10103]: input_userauth_request: invalid user username [preauth] Jul 8 10:09:27 Instance sshd[10103]: Connection closed by 0.0.0.0 [preauth] –
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you've added `AllowUsers` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` configuration file.

To resolve this issue, you'll need to attach the boot disk of your VM instance to a healthy instance as the second disk. Mount it, edit the configuration file and fix the issue.

Here are the steps you can take to resolve the issue:

1. First of all, take a snapshot of your instance’s disk, in case if a loss or corruption happens you can recover your disk.
2. In the Developers Console, click on your instance. Uncheck `Delete boot disk when instance is deleted` and then delete the instance. The boot disk will remain under “Disks”, and now you can attach the disk to another instance. You can also do this step using `gcloud` command:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances delete NAME --keep-disks all
   ```
3. Now attach the disk to a healthy instance as an additional disk. You can do this through the Developers Console or using the `gcloud` command:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances attach-disk EXAMPLE-INSTANCE --disk DISK --zone ZONE
   ```
4. SSH into your healthy instance.
5. Determine where the secondary disk lives:

   ```
   $ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/google-*
   ```
6. Mount the disk:

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir /mnt/tmp
   $ sudo mount /dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-1-part1 /mnt/tmp
   ```

Where `google-persistent-disk-1` is the name of the disk

7. Edit `sshd_config` configuration file and remove `AllowUsers` line and save it.

   ```
   $ sudo nano /mnt/tmp/etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```
8. Now unmout the disk:

   ```
   $ sudo umount /mnt/tmp
   ```
9. Detach it from the VM instance. This can be done through the Developers Console or using the command below:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances detach-disk EXAMPLE-INSTANCE --disk DISK
   ```
10. Now create a new instance using your fixed boot disk.

Comment: i am new to it i don't know how to mount and edit can you provide me link for tutorials anyway thanks hope it works

Comment: I've updated my answer with adding the steps you'll need to take to resolve the issue.

Comment: @RahulSingh - Great to hear that your issue has been solved! Can you please [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that (a) credit is given where it’s due, and (b) the question is marked as closed? Thanks.