# Console Developer instance not working by ssh

Tags: centos, virtual-machines, google-compute-engine

I have two VM instances in google console developer. I can able to open by ssh for instance-1.At the same time  i can't able to connect instance-2 through the browser. I got the following error.

[image]

But i can able to open through terminal ( ssh user@ipaddress ) for particular user.

Please tell me the solution for this.

Comment: Did you modify the SSH configuration on `instance-2`? Are you using password or public-key authentication on `instance-2`?

Comment: @MishaBrukman . Yes we are using public-key authentication on instance-2

Comment: @Anandhakumar R, take a look at your VM serial console output and see if you can find errors related to SSH.

Comment: @AnandhakumarR, please do as Kamran suggests and also see if you have the same issue as in [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/704330/219235).

Answer (score 1):

While you're trying to SSH to your VM instance from the Browser, click on the gear icon on top-right side of the SSH window, click on `Change Linux Username` and enter that particular username which you mentioned you can use it to SSH to your VM instance through terminal.

If this works then the issue is that you're allowing only specific users to SSH to your VM instance.

When SSHing from the Browser, by default, a username for SSH sessions is generated from the email address logged into the account, omitting the domain information. For example, if an email is `jane.doe@gmail.com`, the corresponding username would be `jane_doe`.

Make sure the username generated from your email address logged into the account is allowed to SSH to your VM instance.

Comment: I gave lot of username which i have already can access through ssh command. Even though i tried with new usernames, but i can't login.

Comment: At the same time i can access user1 at instance-1 and can't at instance -2 through gcloud command. Both instance 1 & 2 keys, permissions are same.But it still struggling to connect.

Comment: visit this article where you can find more information about SSHing from the Browser: cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser

Comment: Yes. You are right.But i done this which you mentioned before command. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: check the VM's serial console and see if you can find errors related to SSH?

Comment: It doesn't show error related output